# International Median Income Data at City Level

Tags: city, income, global

I would like to investigate relationships between [Airbnb city listing data](http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html), and median income. In the United States [NHGIS](https://www.nhgis.org/) works lovely, but how about internationally at the city level?

Comment: possibly https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/IPUMS%20International ?

Comment: https://international.ipums.org/ would be the direct source, no?